# Liam opens a bank account and makes deposits at a continuous rate

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, finance

Liam opens a bank account with an initial balance of $2000$ dollars. Let $b(t)$ be the balance in the account at time $t$. Thus $b(0)=2000$. The bank is paying interest at a continuous rate of $3\%$ per year. Liam makes deposits into the account at a continuous rate of $s(t)$ dollars per year. Suppose that $s(0)=1900$ and that $s(t)$ is increasing at a continuous rate of $5\%$ per year (Liam can save more as his income goes up over time). Set up a linear system of the form $$\frac{db}{dt}=m_{11}b+m_{12}s\\ \frac{ds}{dt}=m_{21}b+m_{22}s$$
Find the coefficients $m_x$ and find  $b(t)$ and $s(t)$.

---

I thought this was quite straight forward,

$$\frac{db}{dt}=2000b+2000\cdot0.03s$$
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=1900b+0.05\cdot 1900 s$$

but it is not. If the interest is built on the initial input, $2000$, then wouldn't this be right?

Comment: Not sure I understand what $s(t)$ is (people don't generally add money to an account continuously).  are you saying that the total amount added (between time $0$ and time $t$)  follows the form $s(t)=Ae^{Bt}$ for constants $A,B$? And that $B=.05$?  In any case, I don't see why $\dot s(t)$ should depend on $b(t)$.

Comment: Note:  instead of writing out the form explicitly, you could write $\dot s= Cx$ for a constant $C$...but, again, I think the key question is "is this what you meant by continuously invested amount?"

Comment: I have no idea unfortunately

Comment: Well...I think that's the key to the question.  I'd seek clarification from whomever set the problem.

Comment: The Mathematical association of America

Comment: I would have thought the words translate to $\frac{ds}{dt}=0.05s$  and $\frac{db}{dt}=0.03b+s$

Comment: You can start with $\int_0^1s(t)dt=1.05$ or you have the formula for compound interest which is $P = C (1 + r/n)^{nt}$ and can take the limit as the time between interest payments goes to zero.

Comment: Also note that you've given $s(t)$ as a rate of dollars deposited per year, so it's already the derivative of total amount deposited and you need to be careful not to think of $s$ as the amount deposited.